# Loop in nested array through ng-repeat and create table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object like below on which I am trying to do ng-repeat and create table

```
var data = {
  "1": [
    {
      "row": "1",
      "name": "Acc"
    },
    {
      "row": "1",
      "name": "Eco"
    },
    {
      "row": "1",
      "name": "Mono"
    },
    {
      "row": "1",
      "name": "Mini"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "row": "2",
      "name": "Mono"
    },
    {
      "row": "2",
      "name": "Eco"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried below code where I want row wise data but all the values are getting displayed column wise http://jsfiddle.net/g92zLqa1/2/

The excepted output is

```html
<!--Expected Output -->
<br/><br/>
<h3><b>Expected Output</b></h3>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Acc</td>
    <td>Mono</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eco</td>
    <td>Eco</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mono</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mini</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help on this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Row 2, Cell 2... is it meant to mini or eco?

Comment: @Craig Wayne it's eco as mentioned in question. Display of each values column wise for each row i.e 1,2,3...............

Comment: @user4324324 added code to handle all type of array.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the nest and use the ng repeat on the array with the longest lengths for the rows and add the table elements using the indexOf the ng-repeat on the Array

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="TableController">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat='(key, value) in rows'>{{key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='row in rows.1'>        
     <td >{{row.name}}</td> 
     <td >{{rows.2[rows.1.indexOf(row)].name}}</td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

this is assuming your data will only have 2 rows as given, but you can use a variable if there are more

http://jsfiddle.net/vmhwc8et/

Comment: The above code is not working if I have values in non-sequential format . var data = {"7":[{"row":"7","name":"Acc"},{"row":"7","name":"Eco"},{"row":"7","name":"Mono"},{"row":"7","name":"Mini"}],"2":[{"row":"2","name":"Mono"},{"row":"2","name":"Eco"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Added logic here :

http://jsfiddle.net/aviboy2006/0pgaLqf2/25/

```js
function TableController($scope) {
    let newdata = [];
    let tablerow;
    let finaltable = [];
    for (let key in data) { 
      let value = data[key];
      newdata.push(value.length);
    } 
    console.log(newdata);
    let no_of_row = Math.max.apply(null, newdata);
    for(i=0;i<no_of_row;i++){
       tablerow = [];
       for(let key in data){
           if(typeof data[key][i] === 'undefined') {
           tablerow.push('');
           }
           else{
           tablerow.push(data[key][i]['name']);
           }

       } 
       finaltable.push(tablerow);
    }
    console.log(finaltable);
    $scope.finaltable = finaltable; 
    $scope.rows = data;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="TableController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat='(key, value) in rows'>{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='row in finaltable'>
            <td ng-repeat='cell in row'>{{cell}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```